# DataRows coming out null despite assigning values to them

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linq, datatable

I am trying to learn how to join two data tables into one using Linq.  My linq query is working correctly and I can see expected values in it.  However, when I loop the linq results, and assign the values to a newly created data row and add that row to a new data table, the rows come out empty.

Here is my code:

```
private void btnCombine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var innerJoinQuery =
        from strRow in StrDataTable.AsEnumerable()
        join intRow in IntDataTable.AsEnumerable() 
            on strRow.Field<int>("IntID") equals intRow.Field<int>("ID")
        select new { 
            IntOne = intRow.Field<int>("FirstNum"), 
            IntTwo = intRow.Field<int>("SecondNum"), 
            StrOne = strRow.Field<string>("FirstStr"),
            StrTwo = strRow.Field<string>("SecondStr"), 
            StrThree = strRow.Field<string>("SecondStr")
        };

    DataTable newTable = new DataTable();
    newTable.Columns.Add("IntOne");
    newTable.Columns.Add("IntTwo");
    newTable.Columns.Add("FirstStr");
    newTable.Columns.Add("SecondStr");
    newTable.Columns.Add("ThirdStr");

    newTable.Columns["IntOne"].DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
    newTable.Columns["IntTwo"].DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
    newTable.Columns["FirstStr"].DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
    newTable.Columns["SecondStr"].DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
    newTable.Columns["ThirdStr"].DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");

    foreach (var row in innerJoinQuery)
    {
        DataRow rowToAdd = newTable.NewRow();
        rowToAdd.ItemArray[0] = row.IntOne.ToString();
        rowToAdd.ItemArray[1] = row.IntTwo.ToString();
        rowToAdd.ItemArray[2] = row.StrOne.ToString();
        rowToAdd.ItemArray[3] = row.StrTwo.ToString();
        rowToAdd.ItemArray[4] = row.StrThree.ToString();

        newTable.Rows.Add(rowToAdd);
    }

    dataGridView3.DataSource = newTable;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `DataRow.ItemArray` property with individual values doesn't work - instead, create the `object[]` array and then set the whole thing to the `.ItemArray` property. See this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.itemarray%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for additional examples.

```
foreach (var row in innerJoinQuery)
{
    DataRow rowToAdd = newTable.NewRow();

    object[] items = new object[] {
        row.IntOne.ToString(),
        row.IntTwo.ToString(),
        row.StrOne.ToString(),
        row.StrTwo.ToString(),
        row.StrThree.ToString()
    };

    rowToAdd.ItemArray = items;

    newTable.Rows.Add(rowToAdd);
}
```

Alternately, use the `DataRow` **indexer** directly, which works with individual columns:

```
rowToAdd[0] = row.IntOne.ToString();
rowToAdd[1] = row.IntTwo.ToString();
rowToAdd[2] = row.StrOne.ToString();
rowToAdd[3] = row.StrTwo.ToString();
rowToAdd[4] = row.StrThree.ToString();
```

Additionally, when creating columns, there is a constructor that takes the type which can save you some code. Your first two column types are mismatched.

```
newTable.Columns.Add("IntOne", typeof(int));
newTable.Columns.Add("FirstStr", typeof(string));
```

Answer (score 0):

The first two values appear to be Integers:

```
IntOne = intRow.Field<int>("FirstNum"), 
IntTwo = intRow.Field<int>("SecondNum"),
```

But the `DataType` you assign the columns to is String:

```
newTable.Columns["IntOne"].DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
newTable.Columns["IntTwo"].DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
```

Update those to int's and see if that resolves it:

```
newTable.Columns["IntOne"].DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
newTable.Columns["IntTwo"].DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");

rowToAdd.ItemArray[0] = row.IntOne;
rowToAdd.ItemArray[1] = row.IntTwo;
```

You may also need to supply the `DataPropertyName` for the columns:

```
newTable.Columns["IntOne"].DataPropertyName = "FirstNum";
newTable.Columns["IntTwo"].DataPropertyName = "SecondNum";
...
```

And ensure that the `AutoGenerateColumns` value is set to `false`

```
dataGridView3.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

Comment: Setting the data types of the first to columns to Int32 did not work.

I tried setting the DataPropertyName but that property did not seem to exist.

Setting the AutoGenerateColumns to false caused no table to show up at all in the data grid view.